# Pandas split after month day time from rest of string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe.  I am trying to split a column after the date and time from the rest of the string.

```
df
   data
0  Oct 22 12:56:52 server1
1  Oct 22 12:56:52 server2
2  Oct 22 12:56:53 server2
3  Oct 22 12:56:54 server2
4  Oct 22 12:56:56 comp2
```

Desired output:

```
df
   date              machine
0  Oct 22 12:56:52   server1
1  Oct 22 12:56:52   server2
2  Oct 22 12:56:53   server2
3  Oct 22 12:56:54   server2
4  Oct 22 12:56:56   comp2
```

If I try something like `df["data"].str.extract('^(.*? [0-9]{2}) (.*)$')` it just strips everything after the 22(day)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also pass the exact form of date\time:

```
df['data'].str.extract('(\w* \d* \d*:\d*:\d*) (.*)')
```

output:

```
                 0        1
0  Oct 22 12:56:52  server1
1  Oct 22 12:56:52  server2
2  Oct 22 12:56:53  server2
3  Oct 22 12:56:54  server2
4  Oct 22 12:56:56    comp2
```

Comment: `df['data'].str.extract('(?P<date>\w* \d* \d*:\d*:\d*) (?P<machine>.*)')`

Answer (score 4):

Using `positive lookbehind` to split on `{semicolon}{two numbers}{space}`:

Details:

- `(?<=)` is positive lookbehind (check if anything is before the string)
- `:\d{2}` is pattern: `{semicolon}{two numbers}`
- `\s` is white space

**Conclusion**: we split on a `whitespace` but only if its preceeded by the pattern described above.

```
s = df['data'].str.split('(?<=:\d{2})\s')

df['date'] = s.str[0]
df['machine'] = s.str[1]
df = df.drop(columns='data')
```

Or as `piRSquared` & `jezrael` [suggest in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559343/pandas-split-after-month-day-time-from-rest-of-string/58559476#comment103439330_58559476), in a one-liner:

```
df['date'], df['machine'] = zip(*df.pop('data').str.split('(?<=:\d{2})\s'))
```

**Output**

```
              date  machine
0  Oct 22 12:56:52  server1
1  Oct 22 12:56:52  server2
2  Oct 22 12:56:53  server2
3  Oct 22 12:56:54  server2
4  Oct 22 12:56:56    comp2
```

Comment: Here is some trickery for you (-: `df['date'], df['machine'] = df.data.str.split('(?<=:\d{2})\s').str`

Comment: Also, if the machine name always lacks spaces then we can do an `rsplit`: `df['date'], df['machine'] = df.data.str.rsplit(n=1).str`

Comment: Love it! Added it. How does it overwrights `df['Data']` here? @piRSquared

Comment: It doesn't )-:  you still need to drop it.

Comment: Or better `df['date'], df['machine'] = zip(*df.pop('data').str.split('(?<=:\d{2})\s'))`, then drop not necessary, but not tested

Comment: Note that I edited that comment.  though what you've put is accurate, what I edited to is a smidgen more cheeky.

Comment: Hey @jezrael Nice one (-:

Comment: Yes nice one guys, edited the question accordingly!

Answer (score 3):

#### comprehension

This depends on the data format always being 15 characters.
Also, since we're going to have to drop a column `'data'` anyway, I thought it would be better to simply create a dataframe from scratch.

```
pd.DataFrame([[s[:15], s[16:]] for s in df.data], columns=['date', 'machine'])

              date  machine
0  Oct 22 12:56:52  server1
1  Oct 22 12:56:52  server2
2  Oct 22 12:56:53  server2
3  Oct 22 12:56:54  server2
4  Oct 22 12:56:56    comp2
```

---

#### `rsplit`

Depends on `'machine'` name never having spaces.

This works because the string accessor provided by `pandas.Series.str` is an iterable and can be used in an assignment statement similar to `x, y = (1, 2)`

Also note that I unapologetically took the idea to use [`pop` in this instance from @jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559343/pandas-split-after-month-day-time-from-rest-of-string/58560037#comment103439330_58559476)

```
df['date'], df['machine'] = df.pop('data').str.rsplit(n=1).str

df

              date  machine
0  Oct 22 12:56:52  server1
1  Oct 22 12:56:52  server2
2  Oct 22 12:56:53  server2
3  Oct 22 12:56:54  server2
4  Oct 22 12:56:56    comp2
```

Comment: Maybe add this one in your answer as well: `df['date'], df['machine'] = df.data.str.rsplit(n=1).str`

Answer (score 2):

If the format remains the same:

```
df['date'] = df['data'].str[:-8]
df['machine'] = df['data'].str[-8:]

print(df)

                      data             date   machine
0  Oct 22 12:56:52 server1  Oct 22 12:56:52   server1
1  Oct 22 12:56:52 server2  Oct 22 12:56:52   server2
```

Comment: I like this answer but to be safe I don't think we can depend on the machine names always being 8 characters.  I think we'd be better off doing this from the beginning.  `df.data.str[:15]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
r"(?<=[\S ][\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2} )[\S ]+"
```

I'm not the best with regex there is definitely a better approach but this works